# Skip pipeline execution on several condition

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline

I have one pipeline build called, for example `UAT`. This build is scheduled every 3 minutes. And another build called `DEV`. `DEV` is scheduled every minute. The task is: to run `UAT` only if the last `DEV` execution was `SUCCESS`. If not - skip the execution. And run it after other 3 minutes with the same condition.
How can I achieve that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't schedule your `UAT` job as a separate job but instead trigger the launch once your first `DEV` pipeline finishes with success.
As you are using pipelines you actually have 2 solutions :

1)
Don't call another job but just call a Groovy function to integrate the `DEV` part, such as :

```
node() {
  stage "UAT"
  // Your existing UAT pipeline content here

  stage "DEV"
  git 'http://urlToYourGit/projectContainingYourDevScript'
  pipeline = load 'functions.groovy'
  pipeline.dev()
}
```

2) Just call a second Jenkins job with this kind of line :

```
node() {
  stage "UAT"
  // Your existing UAT pipeline content here

  build job: "dev-job"
}
```

With these 2 solutions you can configure your first job to run every minute and it will trigger the second part/job only if the first one finishes with success (otherwise Jenkins will just fail the build as it would normally do).